# Maximize $\int_t^{t+1}\sin(e^x)\,\rm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, optimization

How to maximize the following integral with respect to $t$?

$$\int_t^{t+1}\sin(e^x)\,\rm{d}x$$

My attempt:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_t^{t+1}\sin(e^x)\,\rm{d}x=\sin(e^{t+1})-\sin(e^t)\overset{!}{=}0$$

However, I stuck at this step.

Comment: From $sin(e^{t+1}- sin(e^t)= 0$, $sin(e^{t+1})= sin(e^t)$.  Sine, of course, is NOT "one-to-one".  $sin(x)= sin(x+ 2n\pi)$ so we have $e^{t+1}= e(e^t)= e^t+ 2n\pi$.  $(e- 1)e^t= 2n\pi$, $e^t= \frac{2n\pi}{e- 1}$.  $t= ln\left(\frac{2n\pi}{e- 1}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(e^{t+1})=\sin (e^t)$$

$$e^{t+1}=2n\pi +e^t$$

Use numerical methods to solve for t.

Comment: Can it be computed without a calculator?

Comment: Read user247327's comment to your original question. You can re-arrange to get an equation in terms of t. And why don't you want to use a calculator?

Answer (score 1):

We then have

$$\sin(e^{t+1})=\sin(e^t)$$

$\sin$ is $2\pi$ periodic and hence

$$e^{t+1}=e^t+2\pi n$$

Using exponential rules and letting $T=e^t$ we can then solve this to get

$$eT=T+2\pi n$$

$$(e-1)T=2\pi n$$

$$T=\frac{2\pi n}{e-1}$$

$$t=\ln\frac{2\pi n}{e-1}$$

Alternatively, $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$, so we have

$$e^{t+1}=\pi(2n+1)-e^t$$

$$eT=\pi(2n+1)-T$$

$$(e+1)T=\pi(2n+1)$$

$$T=\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{e+1}$$

$$t=\ln\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{e+1}$$

Checking a few values, the maximum appears to be $I\simeq0.909026164157$ at $t=\ln(\pi/(e+1))\simeq−0.168531801669$.

For all other $t$, note that by substituting $x\mapsto\ln(x)$ we get

$$I=\int_{e^t}^{e^{t+1}}\frac{\sin(x)}x~\mathrm dx$$

By integrating by parts, this becomes

$$I=\frac{\cos(e^t)}{e^t}-\frac{\cos(e^{t+1})}{e^{t+1}}-\int_{e^t}^{e^{t+1}}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}~\mathrm dx$$

This can easily be seen to be bounded and approaching zero very fast, and so checking the first few values of $t$ numerically suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doubtful you can do this without numerical methods.  Here is your graph:  [image: graph]

so your maximum is at approximately $t=-0.2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(e^{t+1})-\sin(e^t)=0$$
$$\frac{(e^{ie^{t+1}}-e^{ie^t})+(e^{-ie^t}-e^{-ie^{t+1}})}{2i}=0$$
if we let $\alpha=e^{ie^t}$ we can get:
$$\alpha(\alpha^{e-1}-1)+\alpha^{-e}(\alpha^{e-1}-1)=0$$
which should be easy to solve numerically.